# How can I pass a parameter in a custom Joomla button?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I can add a button that calls a function of my choosing with the syntax

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('functionIWant', ... );
```

However, is it possible to pass a parameter along with that function?  I've tried:

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('functionIWant(0)' ... );
```

Which didn't work.

Simply hard coding a hidden `<input>` won't help, as I need a different parameter for each of three buttons.

Currently each button calls a different function, all three of which do the same thing.  I'm trying to reduce code size.  Is there some way I could pass a parameter (either through calling the function in the `custom` declaration, or JS and `setVar()` manipulation.)  Otherwise, do I need to just create three driver functions and use those to call one central function?

Comment: are you submitting a form when any of the three buttons are pressed.?

Comment: Yes, that's how Joomla works.

Comment: attach a function to form onsubmit, check if "task" hidden field is set by then, if it is, then you can add a hidden field to the form through code

Comment: Did you read my question at all?  In order to differentiate by task, I'd have to have three different functions, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @SomeKittens Did you try `functionIWant.apply( this, [ "some", "argument" ] )`?

Comment: Then  try replacing the value of task hidden field with the name of the function that you would like to call and add another field holding the values you want based on the different task values that were assigned through custom buttom. This way you would need a single function.

Answer (score 0):

Create your buttons like this

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('button1', ... );
JToolBarHelper::custom('button2', ... );
JToolBarHelper::custom('button3', ... );
```

Then attach a function to the form

```
<form name='myform' onsubmit='callme()'>

</form>
```

And then create a field and set its value based on the button pressed.

```
<script>

function callme()
{
 var taskval  = document.getElementById('task');
  var form = document.forms['myForm'];
  var el = document.createElement("input");
   el.type = "hidden";
   el.name = "myHiddenField";


 if (taskval=='button1')
   {

   el.value = "myValue1";

   }
 else if ((taskval=='button2')
  {
        el.value = "myValue2";

  }
  else
  {
     el.value = "myValue3";

   }
 form.appendChild(el);  
  document.getElementById('task').value = "functionIWanToCall";

  return true;

}

</script>
```

Comment: I'm hoping to do this all in PHP.